# Problems running a python file in CMD

Tags: python, cmd, pycharm

I use Pycharm as my IDE for python and I have been making a script that talks to an arduino with a rotary encoder, and then sets my pc's volume accordingly, but when I set it up to run on startup, nothing happened. Then I went to the same directory as the venv for pycharm, and tried to run the file from CMD there. It said there is no such module named serial even though I have it installed. [image: Pycharm vs CMD running side by side]

Comment: You need to activate the virtual environment manually when running in cmd. As you can see in the screenshot Pycharm uses "venv" virtual enviroment and cmd tried to run in base.

Answer (score 1):

Pycharm makes use of [virtual environments](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html) for each new project.

Hence, if you want to run it outside of pycharm, the corresponding environment has to be activated.

Assuming that pycharm created this environment in a subfolder "venv", you could create a [batch file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) start_arduino.bat file containing:

```
cd <path to your pycharm project>
call venv\Scripts\activate
python main.py
```